# Expand the Logarithmic Expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the question

$\log \left (\sqrt{x^3\sqrt{y^5\sqrt{z}}} \,\right) $

My work:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiXGJ.jpg

Comment: $z^4$ on your fourth line should really be just $z$. why do you have $z^4$?

Comment: whoops. mistake!

Comment: Your 2nd line should say $\dfrac{1}{2}\left(3\log x + \log\sqrt{y^5\sqrt{z}} \right)$ instead of $\dfrac{1}{2}\log\left(3\log x + \log\sqrt{y^5\sqrt{z}} \right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Please observe that it is
$$
\log (x^{3/2}y^{5/4}z^{1/8}),
$$
hence the last term in your solution should be
$$
\frac18\log z.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\log(a \times b) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ and $\log(a^b) = b\times\log(a)$.

Comment: This isn't helpful. The OP  clearly knows that! Did you check their solution?

Comment: Did you? He tried to do it but didn't do it properly. So I wrote it for him properly.

Comment: How did he get his second and third lines if he didn't already know that?

Comment: Pretty sure that second line is wrong. Too many logs.

Comment: oh come on...it's just the outer log. anyway, I take your point. I'll give you an up vote ;)

Comment: I'll take it. Thanks!